# How do I convert a nested JSON into a comma separated file for analysis? Below are the details

Tags: json, jq

Need to parse the following Json like the following-

new.json

```json
{
  "name": "johnDoe",
  "dept": 45,
  "details": [
    {
      "salary": "76566",
      "weight": "150",
      "height": "160",
      "sex": "male",
      "country": "Usa",
      "State": "NJ"
    },
    {
      "salary": "76560",
      "weight": "160",
      "height": "180",
      "sex": "male",
      "country": "Usa",
      "State": "NC"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "DanLee",
  "dept": 46,
  "details": [
    {
      "salary": "76566",
      "weight": "180",
      "height": "160",
      "sex": "male",
      "country": "Usa",
      "State": "NJ"
    },
    {
      "salary": "76560",
      "weight": "190",
      "height": "180",
      "sex": "male",
      "country": "Usa",
      "State": "NC"
    },
    {
      "salary": "87888",
      "weight": "170",
      "height": "160",
      "sex": "male",
      "country": "Usa",
      "State": "NY"
    }
  ]
}
```

Need name, weight and State information extracted from the above Json format and get a comma separated file for analysis like this:

```
name,weight,State
johnDoe,150,NJ
johnDoe,160,NC
DanLee,180,NJ
DanLee,190,NC
DanLee,170,NY
```

I have just started to use Jq in Linux and would like to understand how such conversion can be done with a step by step explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON input is missing quite a bit of punctuation to make it valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq -r '.name as $name | .details[] | [$name, .weight, .State] | @csv' foo.json
```

gives me:

```
"johnDoe","150","NJ"
"johnDoe","160","NC"
"DanLee","180","NJ"
"DanLee","190","NC"
"DanLee","170","NY"
```

Breakdown:

- `.name as $name` remember the current name as `$name`
- `.details[]` expand the details array one by one
- `[$name, .weight, .State]` construct an array for every element of details
- `@csv` use the built-in CSV conversion.
- `-r`: don't wrap output in JSON strings again.

Comment: You could skip using a variable and just go `[.name] + (.details[] | [.weight, .State]) | @csv`

Comment: Thanks! I will check this solution and get back for any questions.